# Cannot use Unity Ads 2017.3.1.p1

Tags: unity-game-engine

Whenever I try to Play my game in the editor after enabling Unity Ads, I get these errors. Never had a problem before this project. I've tried upgrading to the latest patch (the one I'm on now), serializing assets as text and enabling them manually (they were already enabled), toggling ads, restarting, ect.

[image: Imgur]

EDIT:

I'm not calling any ad things before it's ready. I had this code, but I commented it out just to check if the problem persists:

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

public class Ads : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int ShowEachTry = 3;

    private int TrysCount;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.LogError("Ads aren't working");
        //Advertisement.Show();
    }

    public void SetTry()
    {
        TrysCount++;
        if (TrysCount >= ShowEachTry)
        {
            if (!GameManager.adsDisabled)
            {
                if (Advertisement.IsReady())
                {
                    //Advertisement.Show();
                }
            }
            TrysCount = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I added the `Advertisement.Show()` in the start function *after* the problem started happening just to check.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Advertisement.Show();` on the `Start()` method, Unity hasn't been able to "Get Ads" or in other words it hasn't initialized. What you should do instead is wait about 1 or 2 seconds and then call `Advertisement.Show()`.

Example:

```
Using System.Collections;
IEnumerator Start()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.5f);
    Advertisement.Show();
}
```

Comment: Done. Edited in post. I think that's what you meant?

Comment: This does not provide an answer or additional information. Please don't add comments in the answer section. Meanwhile wait until you have enough reputation for commenting on questions.

Comment: As explained in my question, I added the method in the `Start()` function *after* I began having the issue, just to check if the `Advertisment.IsReady()` was causing the error somehow. I did not have that originally, and removing all calls to the Advertisement class does not have any effect anyway.